# understanding a python descriptors example (TypedProperty)

Tags: python, class, descriptor

Here is a slightly modified version of some code found in a python book:

```
class TypedProperty(object):
    def __init__(self,name,type,default=None):
        self.name = "_" + name
        self.type = type
        self.default = default if default else type()
    def __get__(self,instance,cls):
        return getattr(instance,self.name,self.default)
    def __set__(self,instance,value):
        if not isinstance(value,self.type):
            raise TypeError("Must be a %s" % self.type)
        setattr(instance,self.name,value)

class Foo(object):
    name = TypedProperty("name",str)
    num = TypedProperty("num",int,42)

f = Foo()
f.name = 'blah'
```

My question: why are we creating attributes in f? In the code above, TypedProperty is written such that f.name = 'blah' creates the attribute "_name" in the instance f.

Why not save the values as attributes of the class TypedProperty? Here is what I had in mind:

```
class TypedProperty2(object):
    def __init__(self, val, typ):
        if not isinstance(val, typ):
            raise TypeError()
        self.value = val
        self.typ = typ

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return self.value

    def __set__(self, instance, val):
        if not isinstance(val, self.typ):
            raise TypeError()
        self.value = val
```

Is this an arbitrary design decision?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*All* instances of the class will share the same instance of the descriptor (e.g. `TypedProperty`).  So, if you store the value on the `TypedProperty`, then all instances of `Foo` will have the same value for the `name` and `num` values.  This is *usually* not desirable (or expected) for descriptors.

e.g. if you run the following script:

```
class TypedProperty2(object):
    def __init__(self, val, typ):
        if not isinstance(val, typ):
            raise TypeError()
        self.value = val
        self.typ = typ

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return self.value

    def __set__(self, instance, val):
        if not isinstance(val, self.typ):
            raise TypeError()
        self.value = val


class Foo(object):
    name = TypedProperty2("name", str)

f1 = Foo()
f1.name = 'blah'

f2 = Foo()
print(f2.name)
f2.name = 'bar'

print(f1.name)
```

You'll see the following output:

```
blah
bar
```

so we can see that initially `f2` had  `f1`'s name and then, after changing the name of `f2`, `f1` picked up `f2`'s name.